# detect an input error to then print that error on Python

Tags: python-2.7, input, printing

My question is simple, I will ask the user to give me an input (I'm using 2.7 python) but I want to detect if the user gave me a wrong info. For example, if ask him to write the first planet of the solar system and them he write earth (that isn't), I want to give a print that says that error (he need to type "mercury").

example:

```
planet = input ('please enter the first planet of the solar system') 
print ('your planet is '), planet
```

I just want to make a print error if the person, let say enter earth or maybe not even a planet, let say bed or house.

Comment: Do you have any work so far, and any particular issue that you can't resolve?

Comment: I will give you an example:

planet = input ('please enter the first planet on the solar system')

print ('your planet is '), planet 

I just want to make a print error if the person, let say enter earth or maybe not even a planet, let say bed or house.

Comment: Like this? `planet = input ('Please enter the first planet of the solar system: ') 
if planet == 'Mercury' or 'mercury':
    print ('Correct!')
else:
    print ("That's not the first planet in the solar sytem!!")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the input string using an if statement.

```
planet = input ('Please enter the first planet of the solar system: ')
if (planet != 'Mercury'):
    print("Incorrect Input")
else:
    print ('your planet is '), planet
```

If you are worried about the case of the input (ex: mercury or Mercury), it wouldn't hurt to convert the input string to lower case first and then check.

Like :
    lower_planet = planet.lower()

Or you can mention the restriction in the user prompt itself.